# Importing data from file with ID dependencies

Tags: postgresql

I have this little conundrum going on: I want to bulk import historical data from multiple CSV files like `binance_btc_usd.csv` with structure of `time|value` into table `id|time|value` where `id` refers to the identification of what exchange and what currency pair is going on, which is the file name. I dont want to bake-in an ID into the CSV files, as they may not be valid next time I re-run the script. COPY doesn't seem like the thing I am looking for.

```
CREATE TABLE history_data ( 
    id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    pair  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    time  TIMESTAMP,
    value DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    CONSTRAINT pair_pair_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (pair) REFERENCES pair (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE pair ( 
    id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    exchange  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    base_coin INTEGER NOT NULL,
    quoted_coin INTEGER NOT NULL 
    # and other ... 

    CONSTRAINT exchange_currency_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (exchange) REFERENCES exchange (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    CONSTRAINT base_coin_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (base_coin) REFERENCES currency (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    CONSTRAINT quoted_coin_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (quoted_coin) REFERENCES (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    CONSTRAINT pair_pair_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (pair) REFERENCES pair (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete `create table` statement (including all indexes and constraints) for the table in question. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: There you go...

Comment: The correct ID should be based on the filename, though. I will clarify that.

Comment: I still don't get it. Which part of the filename refers to the ID? Your table has no text column that could match e.g. `btc_usd` or `binance`

Comment: Actually both, that's from the other table.

Comment: So the import should "auto-fill" the `pair` column, not the `id` column?

Comment: It should auto-fill `id` based on the filename, I hold all the information (names, currency names) in the database.

Comment: Dangit, I meant `history_data.pair` of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is a combination of a staging table and some shell scripting.

First step: import the raw file into a staging table, e.g. `history_data_import` which only contains `time` and `value`.

Second step: extract the corresponding values for the `pair` table from the filename and create a SQL statement like the following:

```
with pair_id as (
  select id
  from pair
  where exchange = 'binance' --<< this is "generated"
    and base_coin = 'btc' --<< this is "generated"
    and quoted_coin = 'usd' --<< this is "generated"
)
insert into history_data (pair, time, value)
select pi.id, imp.time, imp.value
from history_data_import imp
  cross join pair_id pi;
```

This assumes that the combination of `(exchange, base_coin, quoted_coin)` is unique in the `pair` table so that only a single row is returned when looking up the id.

How exactly you extract the parts of the filename is a different topic and depends on the operating system you are using. On Linux this is probably a piece of cake for `awk` gurus. But this would better be asked on e.g. https://superuser.com/

Comment: Yeah that looks like only reasonable solution.